# Accepting and printing two strings in nasm assembly

Tags: string, assembly, printing, nasm

I have this code:

```
section .data
   msg3 db 'Enter Two Strings: '
   msg3Len equ $ -msg3

section .bss
   string1Len resb 1
   string1 resb 0
   string2Len resb 1
   string2 resb 0

section .text
   global _start

_start:
   mov eax,4
   mov ebx,1
   mov ecx,msg3
   mov edx,msg3Len
   int 80h

   mov eax,3
   mov ebx,1
   mov ecx,string1
   int 80h

   dec al
   mov byte [string1Len], al

   mov eax,3
   mov ebx,1
   mov ecx,string2
   int 80h

   dec al
   mov byte [string2Len], al

   mov eax,4
   mov ebx,1
   mov ecx,string1
   mov edx,[string1Len]
   int 80h

   mov eax,4
   mov ebx,1
   mov ecx,string2
   mov edx,[string2Len]
   int 80h

   mov eax, 0
   mov ebx, 1
   int 80h
```

I'm having problems in printing two strings. It prints excess and garbage characters. Moreover, when I print three strings, it prints excessive characters. What is wrong with my code when it seems right?

Comment: `resb 0` reserves zero bytes of space (i.e. no space at all).

Comment: what should i change? i changed all resb 0 to resb 1 and it still prints garbage characters.

Answer (score 0):

When you read from stdin to `string1` and `string2` you're writing to memory that haven't allocated (at least not for that purpose). `resb 0` will reserve zero bytes of space (== no space). You should reserve as much space as the size of the longest string you expect to be reading.

Another problem is that you're reading 32 bits from `string1Len` and `string2Len` (`mov edx,[string1Len]`) even though these variables are only one byte in size - which means that you'll be reading 3 bytes beyond the actual variable. Either make the variables dwords (using `resd`), or use the `movzx` instruction to zero-extend bytes into dwords (e.g. `movzx edx,byte [string1Len]`).

Answer (score 0):

As @Michael wrote about using `resd` or `movzx`, this is a better work around.

I tested it in Ubuntu 64bit:

```
; Compile with: nasm -f elf twoString.asm
; Link with (64 bit systems require elf_i386 option): ld -m elf_i386 twoString.o -o twoString
; Run with: ./twoString

SECTION .data
msg     db      'Enter Two Strings: ', 0Ah
msgLen equ $ - msg

SECTION .bss
string1:     resb    255
string2:     resb    255

SECTION .text
global  _start

_start:

    ;print msg
    mov     edx, msgLen
    mov     ecx, msg
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, 4
    int     80h

    mov     edx, 255        ; number of bytes to read
    mov     ecx, string1    ; reserved space to store our input (known as a buffer)
    mov     ebx, 0          ; write to the STDIN file
    mov     eax, 3          ; invoke SYS_READ (kernel opcode 3)
    int     80h

    mov     edx, 255        ; number of bytes to read
    mov     ecx, string2    ; reserved space to store our input (known as a buffer)
    mov     ebx, 0          ; write to the STDIN file
    mov     eax, 3          ; invoke SYS_READ (kernel opcode 3)
    int     80h

    mov     edx, 255
    mov     ecx, string1
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, 4
    int     80h

    mov     edx, 255
    mov     ecx, string2
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, 4
    int     80h
    mov     ebx, 0      ; return 0 status on exit - 'No Errors'
    mov     eax, 1      ; invoke SYS_EXIT (kernel opcode 1)
    int     80h
```